# Make a folder in each subfolder in a directory?

Tags: python, loops

I want to make a folder like this:

```
import os
rootfolder = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\mainf'
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootfolder):
    for i in subdirs:
        os.mkdir('newfolder')
```

`mainf` has 100 subfolders that are empty. I want to make a folder called `new folder` in every one of them. The code above doesn't work.

Comment: `os.mkdir(os.path.join(path,i,'newfolder'))`

Comment: How do you know the code doesn't work? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: true, it would be better to include the error (like `newfolder: directory exists` as I'm guessing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.mkdir('newfolder')` tries to create `newfolder` in the current directory regardless of the loop variables.

You need to join with root & subdir first, check that it doesn't already exist (so you can run it more than once) and create if needed:

```
full_path_to_folder = os.path.join(path,i,'newfolder')
if not os.path.exists(full_path_to_folder):
   os.mkdir(full_path_to_folder)
```

after a discussion in comments, it appears that this works but will iterate uselessly. `path` contains the directory paths when scanning, so no need for the inner loop. Just ignore the last 2 arguments that `walk` yields and do:

```
for path, _, _ in os.walk(rootfolder):
    full_path_to_folder = os.path.join(path,'newfolder')
    if not os.path.exists(full_path_to_folder):
       os.mkdir(full_path_to_folder)
```

Comment: There's no need to use `i` at all since `os.walk` would recursively traverse through all subdirectories anyway. Remove the loop that iterates over `subdirs` or this would result in redundant tests for every subdirectory.

Comment: the test is there so if the program is run a second time with new subdirs created it doesn't crash when encountering the old ones. If it's not a problem, no need to test for this, yes. But you have to create a newfolder for each subdir, so I'm not sure of what you mean.

Comment: I'm talking about the OP's `for i in subdirs:` loop that surrounds your code. That loop is redundant because `os.walk` would recursively traverse through subdirectories anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would try `os.makedirs(path/to/nested/new/directories, exist_ok=True)`.

This will make a directory and all of the necessary directories in between.

Also, look into `os.scandir(path/to/dir)` when you iterate through a directory because it returns these directory objects that are really convenient to use (e.g. has the absolute path, says if it exists, says if it is a file/dir, etc.)